# Getting the large picture in search results with Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In Facebook Graph API, I'm trying to get the large picture of each user in a search result. The following call will give me the small picture of each user:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Bob%20Grossman&fields=name,id,picture&limit=10&type=user&access_token=***

It's rather easy to get the large picture for a single user, by adding the type=large parameter. But that seems to be ignored when searching (probably since there's already a 'type' parameter used to filter the search results).
Is there any way I can do it with Graph API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My approach was to pre-fetch all users with the large and square pictures so that I can choose to use either. As far as I know, you cannot do this with the Graph API because the Graph API is pre-defined to present a specific output.

Let me know if you need more information around this.